# Extract InnerText from HTML

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, html-agility-pack

we have the  tree

```
1. level 1

   1.1. level 1.1

        1.1.1. level 1.1.1
```

We have the HTML of that tree.

We want to extract text with level number (level no = 1, text = "level 1",.. ) What is the best way to achieve this?

---

```
<ol > <li> <h3> <span >level 1</span></h3> <ol> <li> <h4> <span >level 1.1 </span></h4> <ol> <li> <h4> <span >level 1.1.1</span></h4> </li> </ol> </li> </ol> </li> </ol>
```

this is the html. and i am trying to extract in server side using Html Agility Pack. But we did'nt get level number.

Comment: Please paste your HTML code in order for someone to answer the question, and whether you're trying to do this client-side or server-side.

Comment: <ol >
   <li>
    <h3>
     <span >level 1</span></h3>
    <ol>
     <li>
      <h4>
       <span >level 1.1 </span></h4>
      <ol>
       <li>
        <h4>
         <span >level 1.1.1</span></h4>
       </li>
      </ol>
     </li>
    </ol>
   </li>
  </ol>   this is the html. and i am trying to extract in server side

Comment: Please do not use the comments section to paste code. Instead use the `edit` button to update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

use it like:

```
 HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
 doc.Load("file.htm");
 foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//span"])
 {

 }
```

Comment: I am using Html Agility Pack to extract node. But we didn't get the level number along with Text.

Comment: @user2290070 - level number are not coming from a selectable HTML node, so you'll have to parse the link.InnerText to get that number.